# Convert datatable to another datatable By Linq C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

i have a `Datatable` in which there are Columns are
 Assigned to
Storyid,
Completed,
Effort.
 assigned to person can have Same Storyid with diffrent or same (Completed,Effort hours)(image attached)

[input datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkKda.png)

i want dataTable to like in this form where Assigned to Effort and completed hours will be Sum and there storyid's(image attached below
[output datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLwCZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
 var result = yourDatatable
      .GroupBy(e => e.AssignedTo)
      .ToList()
      .Select(eg => new
      {
          AssignedTo = eg.Key,
          CompletedSum = eg.Sum(p=>p.completed),
          EfforSum = eg.Sum(p=>p.effort),
          StoryIds = string.Join(",", eg.Select(i => i.storyid))
      });
```